# POST request with aiohttp returns invalid method for slightly larger files

Tags: python, pdf, post, multipartform-data, aiohttp

I try to implement aiohttp requests for one of my services. I need to send a POST request with a .pdf file to another API. This API accepts multipart/form-data and application/pdf.
Following code works just fine for some .pdf:

```
async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:        
    async with session.post(URL, data={'file': open(file_to_store, 'rb').read()}) as aioresp:
        asynresp = await aioresp.json()
```

But for slightly larger .pdf I get an error from the receiving API with

```
WARNING:  Invalid HTTP request received.
   Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/uvicorn/protocols/http/httptools_impl.py", line 131, in data_received
       self.parser.feed_data(data)
     File "httptools/parser/parser.pyx", line 212, in httptools.parser.parser.HttpParser.feed_data
   httptools.parser.errors.HttpParserInvalidMethodError: Invalid method encountered
```

I assume it has something to do that aiohttp tries to stream larger files but I can't figure out how to format the request in another way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I could not figure the problem out I switched to httpx and all worked just fine and my problem was solved in minutes. Be careful about the timeout, you should set a value that makes sense for your requirements. I can highly recommend httpx: https://www.python-httpx.org/

```
files = {'file': open(file_to_store, 'rb')}

async with httpx.AsyncClient() as client:
    r = await client.post(URL, files=files, timeout=None)
```